# Is first responder or commissioner for fire prevention or security in a company considered as volunteering in an application?

Tags: recruitment, applications

My company's department has several honorary offices like first responder or  commissioner for fire prevention or security.

Can I state this in an application for a new job or isn't it considered as volunteering since it's company inside and I am paid for it indirectly?

Might there even be country specific differences?

Comment: Even if considered as "volunteering" you certainly can state that in an application

Comment: It certainly improves your profile - so I wouldn't hesitate to mention it. I don't think everyone would call it volunteering - but it isn't wrong to call it volunteering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is first responder or commissioner for fire prevention or security in
>   a company considered as volunteering in an application?

In most cases, *unless you are actually a paid* fire fighter or first responder, most would see this as volunteer work.  Keep in mind though that this type of work is seen as **highly valuable by an employer** as most like to spirit of volunteering in employees.

Basically it would be considered a solid **plus** by most employers, and should be on your linkedin profile and on your resume.

Note: There *may* be some country specific differences, but that would make this question a bit broad I think.

Comment: Excellent answer. Also nice from you, that you mentioned paid fire fighters and first responders. In my question this fact is hidden.